# Jenkins Pipeline - Agent used with wrong user

Tags: jenkins, pipeline, credentials, agent

I have a simple Jenkins pipeline script like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'agent2'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                build job: 'doSomething'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the job, it starts correctly on the node "agent2", but it runs as 'jenkins' (the OS shell user of the master server where Jenkins is installed) instead of the OS SSH Shell user of the node.
The node has own credentials assigned to it, but they are not used.

When I run the job "doSomething" on its own and set "Restrict where this project can be run" to "node1" everything is fine. The job then is run by the correct user.

This behaviour can be easily recreated:

**1. create a new OS user (pw: testrpm)**

```
sudo useradd -m testrpm
sudo passwd testrpm
```

**2. create a new node and use this settings:**

[image]

**3. create a freestyle job (called 'doSomething) with a shell step which does 'whoami'**

[doSomething Job XML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cr3wn5oa3log0rs/doSomething.xml?dl=0)

**4. create a pipeline job and paste this code into the pipeline script**

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'agent2'
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                build job: 'doSomething'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[test-pipeline Job XML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pnh66bd3cyyd0aq/test-pipeline.xml?dl=0)

**5. run the pipeline and check the console output of the 'doSomething' job. The output of 'whoami' is not 'testrpm' but 'jenkins'**

Can somebody explain this behaviour and tell me where the error is ?
If I change the "Usage" of the built-in node to "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node", than it works as expected an the "doSomething" job is called with the user testrpm:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Jenkins user or shell os at os layer?

Comment: I mean a shell os user

Comment: Nice!! Share us the job configuration in which you set the expected user or create a copy paste reproducible pipeline. I have a clean Jenkins  ready to use.

Comment: I added 5 steps to reproduce this easily. The freestyle project and pipeline itself dont have any specific settings. Just create empty projects and paste the pipeline code from above. Thanks for you help ! :-)

Comment: mmm to much effort. Help us to help you. I think with docker you could replicate a jenkins master with a jenkins slave.

Comment: Hm sorry I have no knowledge in docker. The steps above take about 2-5 minutes to fully recreate the situation. All empty jobs and only a new OS user and agent on the same system where jenkins runs. I dont know how to make it even easier, sorry

Comment: How are you trying the remote agent? All is in your localhost? Add the whoami linux command in your shell script to print the shell user.

Comment: It's all in my localhost. I added a whoami shell build-step in the doSomething job. It prints out "jenkins" instead of "testrpm" which is the OS user assigned to the agent2. I added both job configuration XML's as downloadable links

Comment: Maybe the error is due to that master and slave are in the same host. I can help you with docker to have to different host in your localhost, one with jenkins and other empty with the  expected os user.  Maybe the jenkins ssh plugin use the user just t stabilish the connection and then switch to the default user. Add `su testrpm`  at the beginning of your script before the whoami and share us the result

Comment: when doing so I get the error:

Started by upstream project "test-pipeline" build number 11
originally caused by:
 Started by user The Dude
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on agent2 in workspace /tmp/agent2/workspace/doSomething
[doSomething] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins260751858148820979.sh
+ su testrpm
Password: su: Authentication token manipulation error
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: If I change the "Usage" of the built-in node to "Only build jobs with label expressions matching this node", than it works as expected an the "doSomething" job is called with the user testrpm. I attached images of the configuration

Comment: having this same issue. changed it as you suggested but still having issues as i think its not running as the user defined in the node/agent. was there anything else you had to do?